# Textfield is remain hidden behind the keyboard - Titanium Android

Tags: android, webview

I am opening an remote web page in webview in android. The remote webpage is include HTML + Javascript + Ajax + ADF (Application Development Framework - ORACLE).

The remote webpage has many textview, dropdown with labels etc...
The problem is when I am trying to write something in textfield, the textfield is not scrolling up automatically, it remains hidden behind the keyboard.

*Troubleshoot:*

I also have tried `windowSoftInputMode = Resize, windowSoftInputMode = Adjustpan, android:Fullscreen:false` in android manifest file.

And I also have tried with this all properties in Webview (Android):

```
cacheMode:Titanium.UI.Android.WEBVIEW_LOAD_NO_CACHE,
enableZoomControls:false,
enableJavascriptInterface:true,
ignoreSslError:true,
keepScreenOn:true,
softKeyboardOnFocus :Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_DEFAULT_ON_FOCUS,
loading:true,
pluginState:Titanium.UI.Android.WEBVIEW_PLUGINS_ON
```

This is working fine in iOS and Android system browser but not working in Titanium Webview in android platform.

*I am using*:

```
Titanium SDK: 5.2.2
Appcelerator Studio : 4.5
Android Device: Samsung, Google Nexus, Motorola
```

Comment: same here, do you solve it by any chance?

Comment: No, i can't till now.

Answer (score 0):

the solution for me was to change the Window's Soft Input Mode property.
Try both Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN or Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE some of them should work
https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-windowSoftInputMode